# Maintaining Image quality when creating scaled bitmap in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I have an image of dimension 960x800 and I am trying to make it fill the screen.

The way I have been currently doing it is by loading the full 960x800 bitmap and using source and destination `Rect` objects. So far example, my destination rectangle is 480x320 (the dimensions of my screen) and the source rectangle will be 960x800.

```
background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background, null);
destRect = new Rect(0,0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
sourceRect = new Rect(0,0, background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
...
c.drawBitmap(background, sourceRect, destRect, backgroundPaint);
```

If I then use a `Paint` object and set dither true when trying the background to the canvas, the image looks absolutely perfect.

```
Paint backgroundPaint = new Paint();
backgroundPaint .setDither(true);
```

I have concluded that this may not be very efficient, causing unnecessary work to be done on each draw call. To combat this, I want to try and do the following:

```
background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background, null);
background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), true);
```

Thereby creating an already sized bitmap, elminating the need for any `Rect` objects. However, when doing this I cannot retain the same image quality as I can with the above method. In fact, the image looks similar to that which can be seen if I do not use a `Paint` object with the aforementioned method. Using the paint object on the scaled bitmap has seemingly no effect.

To give an example of how my image looks, it is similar to [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Dithering_example_undithered_web_palette.png/225px-Dithering_example_undithered_web_palette.png) picture (althought not as severe)

Is there something I can do to get the same image quality?

Answer (score 0):

this is the condition if you want your image to be of width 140nyour height will get resized automatically

```
    Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getResources(), R.drawable.background, null);
    Bitmap bitmap=originalBitmap;
    if (bitmap !=null) {
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();
        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        h = 140*h/w;
        w = 140;
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, w, h, true);
        setIconImage(bitmap);
    }
```