# Scaling ImageView in Android XML

Tags: android, xml, imageview

When scaling an ImageView in XML. Is there a  way that instead of using `android:layout_width="100dp"` and `android:layout_height="100dp"` to scale the image proportionally like doubling/trebling the size etc? This is mainly because I find it fiddly and inaccurate to manually hardcode the 'dp'.

Comment: Scale the image or the ImageView?  What's fiddly about using DP? And it's not inaccurate.  I have apps with very complex layouts that use DP and RelativeLayouts and work fine on any screen you care to run them on.

Comment: Have you considered trying createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)?

Comment: -also get the height and the width with getHeight() and getWidth() function then you can proportionately increase/decrease them

Comment: follow this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372313/maintaining-image-quality-when-creating-scaled-bitmap-in-android